# How to put in text when using XElement

Tags: c#, html, linq

I'm using the new System.Xml.Linq to create HTML documents (Yes, I know about HtmlDocument, but much prefer the XDocument/XElement classes).  I'm having a problem inserting `&nbsp;` (or any other HTML entity).  What I've tried already:

1. Just putting text in directly doesn't work because the & gets turned int &.
   `new XElement("h1", "Text&nbsp;to&nbsp;keep&nbsp;together.");`
2. I tried parsing in the raw XML using the following, but it barfs with this error:

   XElement.Parse("Text to keep together.");

   --> Reference to undeclared entity 'nbsp'.`
3. Try number three looks like the following.  If I save to a file, there is just a space, the `&#160;` gets lost.

---

```
var X = new XDocument(new XElement("Name", KeepTogether("Hi Mom!")));
private static XNode KeepTogether(string p)`
{
    return XElement.Parse("<xml>" + p.Replace(" ", "&#160;") + "</xml>").FirstNode;
}
```

I couldn't find a way to just shove the raw text through without it getting escaped.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: can you provide the XML you try to parse and generate?

Comment: Ooops.  The   didn't come through.  Take another look.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I couldn't find a way to just shove the raw text through without it getting escaped.

Just put the Unicode character in that &nbsp; refers to (U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE) directly in a text node, then let the serializer worry about whether it needs escaping to &#160; or not. (Probably not: if you are using UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1 as your page encoding the character can be included directly without having to worry about encoding it into an entity reference or character reference).

```
new XElement("h1", "Text\u00A0to\u00A0keep\u00A0together");
```

Answer (score 2):

Replacing the & with a marker like ##AMP## solved my problem. Maybe not the prettiest solution but I got a demo for a customer in 10 mins so...I don't care :)

Thx for the idea

Comment: Seems to be the only way I have found either, when you REALLY need the actual ouput string to have, for instance, an `&#10;` in it and not an actual newline or `&amp;#10;`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but I found something and I'm rather surprised!

```
XElement element = new XElement("name",new XCData("<br /> & etc"));
```

And there you go! CDATA text!

Comment: The problem is  that result of (new XElement("name",new XCData("&nbsp;"))).ToString is <name><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></name>.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using numbered entities, they need no declaration.
Numbered entity equivalent to the named entity &nbsp; is &#160;

Comment: that would suffer from the same problem as   as in the & gets escaped.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike amp (&), lt (<) etc, nbsp is not known entity to XML, so you need to declare it.
In XML, e.g. &xyz; is treated as an entity, The parser will reference its value to produce the output.

```
// the xml, plz remove '.' within xml
string xml = "<xml>test&.n.b.s.p;test</xml>";

// declare nbsp as xml entity and its value is " " in this case.
string declareEntity = "<!DOCTYPE xml [<!ENTITY nbsp \" \">]>";

XElement x = XElement.Parse( declareEntity  + xml );
// output with a space between tests
// <xml>test test</xml>
```

or

```
 // plz remove '.' in the string 
 XElement.Parse("<xml>" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Text&.n.b.s.p;keep everything") + "</xml>");
```

Comment: This allows parsing in the XML.  However, if I add do an x.Save("test.xml"), the output file has a space character instead of   between the two test words.  Argh!!!

Comment: Can you replace space with &nbsp when needed? e.g. in HTML context.

Comment: I'm creating a large html document, and then do a doc.Save().  This location is deep in the document, and not easily findable.  
For now I'm going to hack it and remove the space (its between a time and AM/PM).  6:30PM will be fine.  Thanks for your help, though!

Answer (score 1):

You can paste the character as you wish to see it if you copy it somewhere else. Viusal studio allows that.
Though this is hard to do if you need  , it is easy if you need any symbols, for example:

&bull ...just paste •

&harr; ...just paste ↔

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this slightly daft approach which suits me:
String replace all the & with ##AMP## when you store the data....
And reverse that operation on output.
I am using this in conjunction with XElement SQL column and works a treat.

Regards

Neil

Comment: Not necessarily daft -- seemed to be faster than an "extra" `Parse` for me -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723146/is-there-an-xelement-equivalent-to-xmlwriter-writeraw/21098659#21098659

Answer (score -2):

```
&amp;nbsp;
```

Comment: This will result in: `&amp;amp;nbsp;`