# Adding XML string to XElement

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xelement

Hi I need to create an XElement from a string, which can be xml or plain string.

This code

```
    var doc = new XDocument(
        new XElement("results", "<result>...</result>")
    );
```

produces this

```
<results>&lt;result&gt;&lt;/result&gt;</results>
```

But if the string is XML, then I need proper XMl

```
<results><result>...</result></results>
```

Any ideas other than XElement.Parse() because it will throw exception if it is plain text?

Comment: tried `innerXML` yet?

Comment: You could test if the string is xml. E.g. it contains < and > if so use the parser, if not do something else (hard to tell what you wan't when its not XML)

Comment: I was going to say this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414561/how-to-add-an-existing-xml-string-into-a-xelement, but the key point is "other than `XElement.Parse()`", which is actually my question too, if not for the same reasons

Answer (score 1):

See my answer on [Is there an XElement equivalent to XmlWriter.WriteRaw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723146/is-there-an-xelement-equivalent-to-xmlwriter-writeraw/21098659#21098659)

Essentially, replace a placeholder for the content *only if you know it's already valid XML*.

```
var d = new XElement(root, XML_PLACEHOLDER);
var s = d.ToString().Replace(XML_PLACEHOLDER, child);
```

This method may also be faster.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is other way around and it also doesn't look as a best way but you can achieve it like this:

```
object resultContent;

if (condition)
{
    //if content is XmlElement
    resultContent = new XElement("result", "....");
}
else
{
    resultContent = "Text";
}

XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(new XElement("results", resultContent));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about doing this:

```
XElement.Parse(String.Format("<Results>{0}</Results>",possibleXMLString));
```

... and before someone objects to this employing .Parse() method, which is mentioned by OP, please note that this is not the usage that was mentioned.